# Why 'Related Tags?'

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface

The pages showing questions on all the Trilogy sites have on the right side a listing of tags with - I assume - the number of times each of the tags are used in descending order.  This listing is called 'Related Tags.'

Wouldn't a better name be 'Popular Tags?'

Answer (score 2):

The "related tags" are all the tags for all the questions appearing on that specific page you're viewing. It links you to the individual tag pages and gives you their regular use count.

It's *related* to the page you're viewing. I do agree with you that "related tags" is not the best description, and should be titled something like, "tags on this page."

Comment: Alternatively, keep it as related tags, but actually do a little bit of processing to see which tags are related - not just by questions of the page, but by frequency of tags being seen together, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how many people even use the Related Tags feature at all? It's taking up valuable space. Perhaps if few people use this something else could go there.

<sub><sub>(Animated ads would be the natural choice, of course)</sub></sub>

Comment: I use it when I'm asking about something I'm not familiar with, since browsing related tags questions may give me more information to better phrase my question.